# How to read the entire data from a bigquery table in a high efficient way?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery table which having 2M records, I want to read this whole data in order to process it in my machine.
Im achieving that by the following code:

```
com.google.api.gax.paging.Page<FieldValueList> d =  bigquery.listTableData(table,tableSchema , TableDataListOption.startIndex(0).pageSize(5000000));

 Iterator<FieldValueList> sd =  null;

     sd = d.iterateAll().iterator();

     while(sd.hasNext()) {
         FieldValueList fvl = sd.next();

       // do something with the data
     }
}
```

As the result, it takes 7 min to read all the data, because `d.iterateAll()` return the data in a lazy mode, I need something to get the entire data at once or at least faster

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the best option for now is to export to GCS, then read/copy the file(s). You could consider [submitting a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) to have a BigQuery API for reading data quickly; the BigQuery team can provide updates there on upcoming functionality.

Comment: I'd be asking yourself *why* do you want to do this on your machine? It won't scale. Bring your code to the data, not the other way around. You could also use something like Dataflow.

Comment: Im using compute engine, so I can control the size of Ram/CPU, if I dont have this data locally then there is no point :/, so If I used DataFlow BigQueryIO.Read, will get the table data at once?

Comment: IF I used BigQuery.IO.Read will be faster ?

Comment: @TamerSaleh Did you try the option mentioned by Elliott that export to GCS and then read/copy the files to see if it is faster?

Comment: @JL-HN yeah Im implementing this right now

Comment: @ElliottBrossard  @JL-HN now the table is moved to the Cloud storage, now Im trying to read that CSV file in my compute engine, now I saw 2 options to read it, either using `StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService().` or `GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder().build()` , any difference between them regarding performance? can I access both from my GCE?

Comment: No idea. You could consider submitting a separate question.